# Calling setMethod doesn't work to change Boolean value VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, methods, boolean

I have two classes, A main class and a class for calculating some numbers. I'm working with radio buttons where I chose either a Male or Female 
I have a field as Boolean to keep track if it is female or Male chosen. The field is called isFemale
What I want to do is to call a set method from the main class to the calculating depending on what radio button I chose and depending on what I chose it calculates some values that are different between male and female.
The problem is somehow calling a set Method from the Main class doesn't change the isFemale field in the calculation class.
Here is the code:

```
 If btnFemale.Checked = True Then

        bmrCalc.setGender(True)
        MessageBox.Show("Woman")
    ElseIf btnMale.Checked = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Man")
        bmrCalc.setGender(False)
    End If
```

As you can see I've included some message boxes to make sure that the radiobuttons work and they do. The only problem is the *bmrCalc.setGender(boolean)*. It doesn't change the boolean from false to true or vice versa no matter which radio button i chose. The default boolean can't change somehow. The *bmrCalc* object works fine. I have other set Method as Double that works. But this boolean doesn't work somehow..

Here is my field:

```
  Private isFemale As Boolean in the calculation class
```

And here is the setMethod in my calculation class:

```
Public Sub setGender(ByRef female As Boolean)
    isFemale = female
End Sub
```

> **Summary of what the problem is:** 
>   Calling a set method in the main class does not change the Boolean value in the Calculating class instance field

I hope you get the idea. I'm using VB

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, but you should be using a 2-value enum for this instead (Public Enum : Male : Female : End Enum).

Comment: How would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

I've [tried](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xdKGZ3) your code and it appears to be functional. Are you sure you're reading the Boolean value correctly after is has been set? Try debugging the code step-by-step and/or use Watches.

As Dave suggested, you could use an Enum instead of a Boolean:

```
Private _gender As Gender

Public Sub setGender(ByRef gender As Gender)
    _gender = gender
End Sub

Public Enum Gender
    Male
    Female
End Enum
```

You can then set it like:

```
bmrCalc.setGender(BmrCalc.Gender.Male)  
bmrCalc.setGender(BmrCalc.Gender.Female)
```